# resolving parsing ambiguity for syntactic lists

Tags: parsing, syntax, grammar, promela, kframework

I am working on parsing promela code using kframework and encountered with ambiguity in the following grammar: (i.e. both `Sequence` and `DeclLst` is a syntactic list with separator `;`)

```
Sequence ::= Step ; Sequence
           | Step

Step ::= ...
       | DeclLst

DeclLst ::= OneDecl ; DeclLst
          | OneDecl
```

When trying to parse the following fragment of code, an ambiguity occurs:

```
int a;
int b
```

My parser complains that this code can be parsed as either

1. two `Step`s each being a `OneDecl`
   , or
2. One `Step` which is itself a `DeclLst`

Apparently, the core problem is that two syntactic lists (i.e. `Sequence` and `DeclLst`) share the same separator `;`.

link to [PROMELA grammar](https://spinroot.com/spin/Man/grammar.html)

I've searched for this kind of ambiguity problems but all I could find was about associativity or operator precedence issues which seemed not quite relevant.

Can anyone enlighten me with how to fix this grammatically?
(or even better, with kframework specific solutions)

Comment: Yup: The error message is correct; the promela grammar itself is entirely ambiguous! You can only fix this by not using the grammar from the promela site and amending the language you recognise. Perhaps by not being context free, but context sensitive.